# Strategic Advice: Using dictionary objects to move between forms

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary

I am writing a game in c# using Windows Forms.  I've chosen this to be a fun task while at the same time helping me learn.  I have a game workflow of 8 forms.  The design and coding is going well within the each forms.  I have prototype models working of everything I want to do.

However the game workflow is circular. The user will be transferred round and round 8 forms as the game progresses.  I would like to use some sort of bundle to pass what I need between the forms.  I am quite happy to read the documentation and work out how I can do this - perhaps with a dictionary object.

My question is more about the strategy and I had two possible options in mind.  Please could you recommend the preferable path I should investigate (or even a third improved option) when moving from one form to another in the workflow?  I've used nextForm and previousForm here as terms to refer to the form the user is about to leave and the form they're about to use.

1. Create a new instance of the nextForm class and pass the required objects between forms as a bundle.  Kill previousForm.  An instance will be recreated when needed.  I see this as a "Frogger" analogy when the frog jumps from one log (which then sinks) onto a newly created log, carrying a briefcase of anything he needs between the two logs.
2. Create a single instance of all 8 forms that I need.  Transfer the user between the forms (again using the bundle of objects required) but use previousForm.Hide() and nextForm.Show() methods.  Here I'd be refreshing the existing nextForm instance with the new data from previousForm and making it visible while making nextForm disappear until it's needed again.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is more better then option 2. If you do not need to preserve previousForm status than my suggestion is not follow option 1. Because it will unnecessary consume memory. More user may not came to previousForm, so why it will need to remain hide on background.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.  Sorry - I should have added that it is a single user game and during the course of the game the user will cycle through the workflow perhaps 20 times.

Comment: "workflow perhaps 20 times" --- So definitely option 2 is not an option

Comment: Hi Nazmul, why is it not an option to have a single instance of the 8 forms in memory and hide/show each when necessary so that only 1 is visible at any given point in the workflow?